# Why is "Fey" translated as "Inefable"?

Tags: translation, cursed

So far as I can tell, in the series *Cursed*, the Spanish version decided to call the Fey *los Inefables*.

Now, it is easy enough to understand why they did not simply go with the English word "Fey," since it is easily confused with the Spanish word *fe*, meaning faith. However, I cannot understand the motivation behind choosing *inefable*, which means precisely ineffable, indescribable, or unfathomable, particularly relative to a more common translation like *hada*, or fairy, used in phrases like *cuento de hadas*, fairy tale. In fact, I believe *hada* even is etymologically similar: both it and "fey" make reference to fate, although one is Germanic and the other Latinic. Even *elfo*, or elf, would seem like a more logical choice.

In short, this translation choice seems rather unusual, since it departs from the usual translation in favor of a description that does not seem quite right. The Fey are not unknowable in their motivations; quite the contrary, and there seems to be no taboo related to mentioning them among the humans. Also, since it is a four-syllable word, it would probably be harder to make it fit the lip movements of the actors.

Is there some element of the plot that explains this word choice? Or, failing that, is there any official information on the translation of this essential plot word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not come across a definitive response from someone concerned with translating or dubbing the series, but "El Sabanero X" (a film and tv critic) gives a nice discussion [here](https://sabanerox.com/2020/07/17/maldita-cursed-quienes-son-los-inefables/). To translate a key paragraph:

> A 100% accurate translation of *Morgana le Fay*, would be *Morgana the
> Fairy*. And similarly, the term to refer to the peoples of which Nimue
> is a part, would not be "ineffable", but "the fairy people". Now it is
> possible to understand why the translators and dubbers would be so
> reluctant to use the term, since in Spanish a fairy (una hada) is
> considered to be a tiny flying sprite, like Tinkerbell, and not
> beings similar to humans.

Incidentally, the translators of Harry Potter faced a similar dilemma, and some of the witches and wizards that worked at the Ministry of Magic, the "Unspeakables", were translated as "Los Inefables". Sometimes it is just not possible to give a faithful translation, and "inefable" seems to have become something of a go-to solution for magical beings.

Comment: Parece que no soy el único que pensó que era rara esa elección.

Comment: Sí, pero "unspeakable" literalmente quiere decir "inefable", lo que no se puede decir, a diferencia de "Fey" que no tiene nada que ver. Una es una traducción fiel y la otra parece carecer de justificación. ¿Por qué no "elfo"? Sirve para los "elves" de Tolkien y para muchos más, y lo de las orejas puntiagudas no tiene demasiada importancia.

Comment: Por cierto, sabrás que los Inefables son quienes trabajan en el Departamento de Misterios, no tod@s l@s emplead@s del Ministerio. Pero bueno, supongo que la persona que la tradujo, sobrecargada de trabajo, podría haber usado Harry Potter como base para sus traducciones ignorando que "inefable" no hacía referencia a todos los magos sino a un grupo selecto.

Comment: Sí, su elección es extraña, pero estoy de acuerdo en que la palabra "hada" no sirve, y una alternativa es necesaria. Quizás "fata" como fata Morgana https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fata_Morgana - se usa en los libros de Rothfuss para significar "Fae" por ejemplo.

No estoy de acuerdo contigo en que "Unspeakable" es completamente equivalente a "Inefable". Permítame que pase al inglés un momento. A common phrase is "an unspeakble atrocity". This would not be the same as "an ineffable atrocity". Unspeakable and ineffable do have subtly different tones.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is the first I have heard of the series; I am answering only from a linguistic perspective.

Are the fey "not unknowable in their motivations"? The classic attribute of the Fey is their otherworldliness, especially in their minds and motivations. Granted this series seems to have its main characters be fey, so their motivations will probably be revealed more than usual, but it remains a good term. Even if the Fey are "effable" to the view, they are seen as "Ineffable" by others.

Fairy (or, as it sometimes spelled "Farie") is related to Fey, etymologically. However, to paraphrase Tolkien, fairies have been bastardized into diminutive sprites (e.g. Tinkerbell), especially in children "bedtime fairy tales". Something similar has been done with elves, building off the themes of magic and nature, via the filters of e.g. Dungeons and Dragons.

To avoid conflation with these other popular culture ideas, the show has probably tried to pick a less usual name, that still harkens back to the original conception of the Fey.

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable for not knowing about the series, but the Fey are completely analogous to humans in their motivations within the series, without being either ineffable in reality, nor being seen as ineffable by humans. Nor is "inefable" a translation that has been used before for "Fey," to my knowledge, so it is not just tradition.